# AFNetworking UIGestureRecognizer inside setCompletionBlockWithSuccess

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, afnetworking-2, uitapgesturerecognizer

first of all thanks for all your help.

I'm trying to download several images with AFNetworking, the question is that when I try to add a gesture recognizer inside the block success part and after finished I get an error.

This is my code.

```
- (void)loadPictures {

    NSArray *listItems = [[_dictForData objectForKey:@"imgs"] componentsSeparatedByString:ITEM_SEPARATOR];

    NSLog(@" == Num Images %d", [listItems count]-1);

    NSMutableArray *imgNames= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<[listItems count]-1;i++)
    {
        NSString *nameImage = [listItems[i] componentsSeparatedByString:TAG_SEPARATOR][1];
        NSLog(@" == Name Image %@", nameImage);
        [imgNames addObject: nameImage];
        NSLog(@"== %@", [imgNames objectAtIndex:i]);
    }

    // Setup the array of UIImageViews
    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(NSString *name in imgNames) {
        NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@%@", SERVER, URL_FILES,[_dictForData objectForKey:@"id"],URL_IMAGES_HI,name];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
        NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


        AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
        requestOperation.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];
        [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
            UIImageView *tempImageView;
            tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
            tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            tempImageView.image = responseObject;
            [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];
            UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
            singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
            [tempImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
            [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
            if ([imgArray count] == [listItems count]-1) {
                //CGSize pageSize = self.scrollView.frame.size; // scrollView is an IBOutlet for our UIScrollView
                NSUInteger page = 0;
                NSUInteger widthPicture  = 100;
                NSUInteger heightPicture = 100;

                for(UIView *view in imgArray) {

                    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
                    // This is the important line
                    //view.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 10, 0, pageSize.width - 20, pageSize.height);
                    view.frame = CGRectMake(widthPicture * page++, 0, widthPicture - 5, heightPicture);
                    // We're making use of the scrollView's frame size (pageSize) so we need to;
                    // +10 to left offset of image pos (1/2 the gap)
                    // -20 for UIImageView's width (to leave 10 gap at left and right)
                }

                //self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);
                self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake((widthPicture + 5) * [imgArray count], 100);
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Image error: %@", error);
        }];
        [requestOperation start];


    }
}

-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");

}
```

EDIT:

The error is an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7000000C) when i tap the imageview.

I need to tap over the images created and show the single tap on imageview.

What I'm doing wrong? or how could I solve it?.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my Inglish

Comment: please provide the error message .!

Comment: you are not adding UIImageView to any view .. !!! 
[myAwesomeView addSubview: tempImageView];

Comment: add UITapGestureRecognizer inside loop after you add image to view.
[self.scrollView addSubview:view];

Comment: Could you show your method `tapDetected` ?

Comment: @KIDdAe : its already placed down -(void)tapDetected

Comment: In your current code only one image is added in `imgArray`, are you sure that the crashing images is the one from this block of code ?

Comment: @KIDdAe : m still wondering how is he initialising  `imgArray` 
and y is he using a loop inside a block !!.

Comment: well im going to explain what i want :S. I recive from a json array several img sources, I download them and I need to put them in a scrollbar. like an image gallery. I put all my code.

Comment: @MikelSanchez : your code is working fine .. 
remove `if ([imgArray count] == [listItems count]-1) {` condition.

Comment: I don't know why but its not working, i cant quit that if, its has to be done when all the images have finished downloading.

Comment: I solved the problem taking the code out of the controller that was inside a view.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding your UIImageView to an imgArray `[imgArray addObject:tempImageView];`
directly add `[self.scrollView addSubview:tempImageView];` 
comment it from loop. i completely understand you are using loop for `CGRectMake`.

still tested your code and its completely working
i removed this line `if ([imgArray count] == [listItems count]-1) {`

```
UIImageView *tempImageView;
    tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    tempImageView.image = responseObject;
    [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];
    [self.view addSubview:tempImageView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [tempImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [tempImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: Yes sorry i add it later when all the operations finish. I edit again sorry.